# How to solve the definite integral involving greatest integer function?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $ [\cdot] $ denote the greatest integer function.  Then how to evaluate the integral  $$I=\int_0^2  [x^2]dx?$$

Comment: Please help to edit and solve

Comment: Please check that I haven't altered the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\int_0^2\lfloor x^2\rfloor dx=\int_0^1 0dx+\int_1^\sqrt21dx+\int_\sqrt2^\sqrt3 2dx+\int_\sqrt3^23dx$$

Comment: Integrals are additive on intervals; I chose intervals where $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ is constant, so the integrals are easy to evaluate